# slomo by rendering baked animation with higher frame?

Tags: rendering, keyframes, rigid-body-simulation, frame-rate

I made a rigid body animation which I already baked to keyframes. Besides that, there are some other keyframes for camera movement etc. in the scene. I am editing the animation in premiere and I would like to use time remapping in premiere to slow the animation down at some point. Now I was wondering if there is a way to render the animation out with twice as many frames. I built the whole scene with 30fps.

- I tried to increase the "time stretching" from 100 to 200 in the render settings which seems to have no effect.
- If there is no way to solve this in the render settings, I was thinking about stretching all the keyframes since the animation is baked to keyframes. But it's like hundreds of keyframes which would be a pain to stretch them all. Maybe there is a fast way to do that?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Why don't you just set it to 60 fps and then increase the time stretching? That way it will have to render more frames and will fit the sequence.